# jquery not working! I don't get whats the problem is

Tags: jquery, html

jquery not working! it worked when I used the script tag but it doesn't work when I have made an additional file of jquery

I tried changing the file name

//HTML file location: C:\Users\junes\OneDrive\docs\Visual Studio Code\html\index.html

---

"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ="javascript/js1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

### "

//jquery file location: C:\Users\junes\OneDrive\docs\Visual Studio Code\javascript\js1.js
"

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#p1").mouseup(function(){
      alert("Mouse up over p1!");
    });
  });
```

"

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: "jQuery not working" is not a very useful question title, and it is almost certainly *your* code which is not working. I suspect the bug is that you are using \ instead of / in the script tag's `src` attribute.

Comment: just after your document ready, try add alert("test"), if you dont see it then you havent included the js file correct.

Comment: <script src ="javascript\js1.js"></script> is not valid try <script src ="javascript/js1.js"></script> or <script src ="./javascript/js1.js"></script>

Comment: you can provide minimal of working code by adding snipet?

Comment: i tried using alert("test") but it is not working neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is locate here

```
Visual Studio Code\html\index.html
```

But your JS file is located here

```
Visual Studio Code\javascript\js1.js
```

If you write

```
<script src ="javascript/js1.js"></script>
```

This is a relative url, so file must be located here (look the html folder)

```
Visual Studio Code\html\javascript\js1.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct only problem in path of the file of js.
According to me if u write this code in html page(in script tag) it works.